# How would we falsify Inflation Theory?

Tags: cosmological-inflation

**What experimental results would falsify inflation theory?**

Simply put, inflation seems antithetical to good science theory.

A process that starts at exactly the right time, is of exactly the right magnitude, and lasts for exactly the correct period of time required to explain observational results.  Without recurring, without a testable triggering event, without a testable mechanism for ceasing at the correct timescales needed to explain CMB results.

Something untestable that exists solely to plug into your equations to explain what's otherwise an anomaly (CMB uniformity), it's the definition of a mathematical cheat. To be sound theory it must be falsifiable (not just infinitely modifiable).  My concern is that once something can't be falsified, we're setting ourselves up for generations of anchoring, where new ideas can't find a foothold because bad theory is taken as a necessary starting point for students entering the field.

What would have to happen for us to abandon inflation theory and pursue another avenue?

Comment: Your question is reasonable, but this statement is just wrong: "A process that starts at exactly the right time, is of exactly the right magnitude, and lasts for exactly the correct period of time required to explain observational results." It is actually the other way around, there are a huge range of possibilities that produce very similar (observable) outcomes.

Comment: You just need to come up with a theory that better fits all of the evidence. That is all...

Comment: @RobJeffries define a "huge range." for the CMB temperature variation to match observed results my understanding was the constraints on the duration of the inflationary expansion period were quite tight.

Comment: You are perhaps more informed than me. I thought there were still orders of magnitude uncertainty. If there were not, then it seems to me that any theory would be eminently falsifiable by simply measuring the CMB temperature varations and then I don't see what your question is about.

Comment: Plus the situation is not as you claim. There are competing ideas. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ekpyrotic_universe Part of the problem is calling inflation a "theory". I do not think it merits that status at all. It is a model or perhaps even a scenario.

Comment: However, your headline question is still a good one.

Comment: Penrose has gone about this for years and his criticisms have fallen on deaf years :/